# Custom command loop for selenium?

Tags: python, string, selenium, loops, xpath

I would like to make a command loop to go down a column of checkboxes and have selenium webdriver check 10 and then scroll down and continue for a set number of reps.

I have been able to code the first checkbox click and the scroll down after. I need to be able to create a XPATH string for the next checkboxes and make a loop to go for a set number of rounds.

This is my code so far

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#u_0_u > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > "
                                                                  "div:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) "
                                                                  "> ""td:nth-child(1) > label > span")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400)")
```

This is the XPATH with the variable needed to be sequentially changed in **bold**

```
//*[@id="u_0_u"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/**tr[1]**/td[1]/label/span
```

Here is the HTML for the first 3 rows.

```
<tr class=""><td class=" _100u"><label class="_55sg _kv1"><input name="select_single_row_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="100003109554020"><span class="_66ul"></span></label></td><td class=" _100u"><div direction="left" class="clearfix"><div class="_ohe lfloat"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100003109554020/picture?width=32&amp;height=32" class="img _8o _8r img" alt=""></div><div class=""><div class="_42ef _8u"><div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100003109554020" class="_3cb8" href="/100003109554020">Caio Augusto</a></div></div></div></div></td><td class=" _100u"><abbr aria-label="4 days ago" class="livetimestamp" data-utime="1587140162">04/17/20</abbr></td></tr>

<tr class=""><td class=" _100u"><label class="_55sg _kv1"><input name="select_single_row_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="100033497255249"><span class="_66ul"></span></label></td><td class=" _100u"><div direction="left" class="clearfix"><div class="_ohe lfloat"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100033497255249/picture?width=32&amp;height=32" class="img _8o _8r img" alt=""></div><div class=""><div class="_42ef _8u"><div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100033497255249" class="_3cb8" href="/100033497255249">Cam Ailiff</a></div></div></div></div></td><td class=" _100u"><abbr aria-label="a week ago" class="livetimestamp" data-utime="1586814525">04/13/20</abbr></td></tr>

<tr class=""><td class=" _100u"><label class="_55sg _kv1"><input name="select_single_row_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="691216152"><span class="_66ul"></span></label></td><td class=" _100u"><div direction="left" class="clearfix"><div class="_ohe lfloat"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/691216152/picture?width=32&amp;height=32" class="img _8o _8r img" alt=""></div><div class=""><div class="_42ef _8u"><div><a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=691216152" class="_3cb8" href="/691216152">Dave Anderson</a></div></div></div></div></td><td class=" _100u"><abbr aria-label="7 weeks ago" class="livetimestamp" data-utime="1582826382">02/27/20</abbr></td></tr>
```

Please advise on how to make this possible.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @Sri It is within a facebook page to manage people who have liked. I'm not sure you could see the HTML as there is login. I could share a longer portion of the HTML and a screenshot with you?

For reference, here is the link anyways. https://www.facebook.com/eddiejagmedia/settings/?tab=people_and_other_pages&ref=page_edit

Comment: Yes, please update your post with the sample HTML. I do not have a facebook account

Comment: @Dri do you want the code for the entire page HTML or the table will do?

Comment: The table will do

Comment: @Dri The HTML of the table is much too long for the post section. Should I just post a few rows in manually?

Comment: Sure, that will work. As long as I can see a few checkboxes.

Comment: @Dri, updated the post to reflect the HTML of the first 3 rows

Comment: elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='select_single_row_checkbox[]'][@type='checkbox']") will return a list of all available checkboxes on the page. Loop over elems and click each of them. Once you have done that, scroll down and repeat. You can keep track of the value attribute of each elem to make sure you do not doubleclick a checkbox.

Comment: @Sri unfortunately did not find the element that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path='PATH TO CHROME DRIVER')

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/CHANGE_PAGE_USERNAME_HERE/settings/?tab=people_and_other_pages&ref=page_edit")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']").send_keys("EMAIL")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']").send_keys("PASS")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'u_0_')][@value='Log In']").click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.refresh()
#time.sleep(5) #turn on to sort through banned
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='u_0_u']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/span[1]").click()
#time.sleep(5)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js_s']/div/ul/li[4]/a").click()
#time.sleep(9)

f = 1
whitelist = 5000
while f <= whitelist:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0,5000)')
    time.sleep(1)
    f += 1
    continue

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,0);")
toggle_all = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_0_u']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/"
                                                              "thead/tr/th[1]/label/span")))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(toggle_all).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", toggle_all)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, float(.0001))
i = 1
targets = 100  # this is where you change how many checkboxes will be selected
while i <= targets:
    xpath_string = "//*[@id='u_0_u']/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[1]/label/span"
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_string)))
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    i += 1
    continue
```